# Incompatible pointer type assigning "NSMutableArray" to "NSArray"?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This is my code

```
 NSMutableArray * reversedNamesArray; //theres about a thousand variable already stored in here, this is just for documentation
reversedNamesArray = [reversedNamesArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

//Incompatible pointer type assigning "NSMutableArray" to "NSArray"
```

The message above is what i get, i know what it means, but i don't want to take an extra step of copying an NSMutableArray of a thousand variable to a NSArray is there any cast i can use to fix the warning, it doesn't affect my code, but i just want a fix for it. and can you explain why they are not compatible, they NSMutableArray and NSArray should use the same amount of bytes so i don't see why they are incompatible in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` is implemented in `NSArray` and returns an `NSArray` **even when called on an NSMutableArray.**

You should use one of the sort methods implemented in `NSMutableArray`. This would work:

```
[reversedNamesArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Thank you that explains why it does that, i didn't know that it would return an NSArray! Thanks

Comment: @OPJ In this case you should not assign the result to the `reversedNamesArray` variable. `sortUsingSelector:` just sorts the array directly, so the change is already done. It also returns void, so the compiler should complain if you try to assign the return value to a variable.

Comment: @Monolo thanks, I had noticed my mistake seconds after posting and corrected it. You must have gotten that unedited version.

Comment: No, this was to OPJ who used the term "return an NSArray", @GerdK

Comment: @Monolo Though if you do use the `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method from NSArray you **do** need to assign the result, as it returns a new and sorted array.

Answer (score 5):

@GerdK's answer is the right one, but I thought I would explain why you cannot just cast an `NSArray` into `NSMutableArray`. If you could, major optimizations would be lost. Consider the following:

```
NSArray *first = @[...];
NSArray *second = [first copy];
```

This is extremely cheap. `second` just adds an extra `retain` onto `first` and we're done. On the other hand:

```
NSMutableArray *first = [NSMutableArray arrayWith…]
NSArray *second = [first copy];
```

This is more expensive. In order to create `second`, we actually have to create new array and copy the pointers over and add extra retains.

Now, imagine what you're requesting were legal:

```
// Not legal, but let's say it were
NSArray *first = @[...];
NSMutableArray *second = (NSMutableArray *)[first copy];
```

Now `[NSArray copy]` has to be defensive against this. It has to implement `copy` as a full (expensive) copy. That's a real performance loss.

You might say "But I'll just use `copy` when I want to really copy and `retain` when I want to retain." Sure, but that's not good enough. Say I want to store an immutable copy of something I'm passed:

```
- (void)setSomething:(NSArray *)array {
   _something = [array copy];
}
```

This is a very efficient and correct setter. If I pass a real `NSArray`, then it's cheap (and this is probably the normal case). If I pass an `NSMutableArray` (it's a subclass, so I can do that), then I automatically make a real copy (so the object can't change behind my back). You get this kind of optimization for free by keeping mutable and immutable objects separate. Otherwise, I'd have to interrogate the object and ask if it were mutable and then make decisions based on that.